# LIMIT offset or OFFSET in an UPDATE SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, limit, offset

I have a table similar to this:

```
| 0 | X  |
| 1 | X  |
| 2 | X  |
| 3 | Y  |
| 4 | Y  |
| 5 | X  |
| 6 | X  |
| 7 | Y  |
| 8 | Y  |
| 9 | X  |
```

I'd like to replace first 2 occurrences of `X` with `X1`, and then 4 next occurrences with `X2` so that the resulting table looks like this:

```
| 0 | X1 |
| 1 | X1 |
| 2 | X2 |
| 3 | Y  |
| 4 | Y  |
| 5 | X2 |
| 6 | X2 |
| 7 | Y  |
| 8 | Y  |
| 9 | X2 |
```

The table in question is of course much bigger and the number of occurrences would thus be higher too so manual editing is not a solution.

I'd like to do something like this:

`UPDATE table SET column = 'X' WHERE column = 'X2' LIMIT 90, 88`

but unfortunately MySQL doesn't seem to support OFFSET in UPDATE queries... Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

`UPDATE table SET column = 'X1' WHERE id IN(SELECT id FROM (SELECT id FROM table WHERE column = 'X' LIMIT 2) as u);`

and then

`UPDATE table SET column = 'X2' WHERE id IN(SELECT id FROM (SELECT id FROM table WHERE column = 'X' LIMIT 4) as u);`

Comment: This version of MariaDB doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'

Comment: I had the same issue but was because I skipped the first (outer) `select` statement. The fact that both are retrieving `id` is a workaround to this limitation.

Answer (score 13):

I don't know whether you have id filed available in table or not, but you can use **WHERE id BETWEEN 88 AND 90**, MySQL does not support Offset in update query, but you can do this by limiting using **BETWEEN** command