# Update Table Column in Multiple Rows based on a Selection in SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have selected a group of `rows` using Select statement in `SQL`, and I'm trying to figure out how to update a column in this `table` to a value based on said `selection`.

The Selection:

```
SELECT user.userID FROM user WHERE user.status = '1' or user.status = '2' LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 50;
```

The Update:

```
UPDATE user SET user.status = '3';
```

The end result I am looking for is the `status column` of all the `selected users` be updated to '3'. I want to be able to do this in one `SQL query` and not have to loop or anything.

Thanks for any insight!

UPDATE:

Sorry! I forgot to add the `offset`. I want to select the rows after the first 50 returned rows.
So I want all the rows after the first 50 that match the criteria, to have the status column changed to 3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**OLD**

UPDATE user SET user.status = '3' WHERE user.status = '1' or user.status = '2';

Please try this query...

**NEW**

After Edit Question (As per offset)

try this below query for your offset.

```
UPDATE user SET user.status = '3' where  user.userID NOT IN(Select
userid from 
(SELECT userID as userid FROM user WHERE status = '1' or status = '2' LIMIT 50) 
as temptbl);
```

Comment: Alternatively `WHERE user.status IN ( '1' , '2' )`

Comment: @YograjSudewad Really? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/782915/mysql-or-vs-in-performance

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE user SET user.status = '3' where user.status in ('1', '2');
```

Updated:

```
UPDATE user SET user.status = '3' where user.userID in (SELECT user.userID FROM user WHERE user.status = '1' or user.status = '2' LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 50);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Try this

```
UPDATE user SET user.status = '3' WHERE user.status IN ( '1' , '2' )
```

Answer (score 0):

### new:

Use two subselects (Thanks to Yograj Sudewad for poiting me to my mistake)

```
UPDATE user 
SET user.status = '3'
WHERE user.userID IN (
    SELECT userId 
    FROM (
        SELECT user.userID 
        FROM user 
        WHERE user.status = '1' or user.status = '2' 
        LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 50
    ) AS tableWithNoName
)
```

---

### old:

You could just use the `WHERE` part from your `SELECT` in your `UPDATE` as well. 
Like so

```
UPDATE user 
SET user.status = '3'
WHERE user.status = '1' 
    OR user.status = '2';
```

But if you want the UPDATE from the uid list, then:

```
<?php
// The uid list from the select may be 
$uid_list = array(1,4,7,12,401);
// then you could make
$sql = "
UPDATE user 
SET user.status = '3'
WHERE user.userID IN (" . implode(',', $uid_list) , ")

";
```

Comment: @Guy Then use a subselect like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10728775/limit-offset-or-offset-in-an-update-sql-query) See my updated answer

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. I fed it exactly that but it complained about the query and it failed.

Comment: What exactly does it complain about?

Comment: @HerrSerker Mysql cant allow u to use same table in the inner query directly because you are performing update data.

Comment: MySql gives Error like:"You can't specify target table 'User' for update in FROM clause"

Comment: @YograjSudewad I see, you have to use a subselect in a subselect.