# update whole column with an array input from top to bottom without id info using prepared statements

Tags: php, mysqli, sql-update, prepared-statement, offset

I have 2 tables for my articles in DB:

1. articles
2. tags

`tags` table structure and current state:

primary key for my `tags` table is `tag` column.

```
tag     |   post_ids    |   count   |
-------------------------------------
a       |   2,0         |           |
b       |   1,2,0,0     |           |
tag1    |   1,2,0,0     |           |
j       |   2,0         |           |
```

**I want to update `count` column** after any INSERT (*new post*) or UPDATE (*existing post*) action and I want to do it with prepared statements.

For the time being, I can dynamically construct the input: `$array = array("2","4","4","2")` which is the related values of the `count` column to be updated.

And with the code below; I tried to update the `count` column however count always updates with value = 2 for all `count` rows.

- I have no warning/error.
- MySQL version: 5.5
- I have to update 1st `count` row with the `$array[0]`, 2nd `count` row with the `$array[1]` ... So I have to utilize `LIMIT`, `OFFSET` arguments
- I learnt that *MySQL doesn't allow OFFSET in UPDATE queries*
- I am not capable to write complex queries, I searched SO and found the Q&A: [LIMIT offset or OFFSET in an UPDATE SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10728775/limit-offset-or-offset-in-an-update-sql-query)
- It seemed to me the sql I used from that Q&A is logically suitable for my case however I didn't understand the sql.
- I am not 100% sure that problematic area is the sql.

I want to correct my code and learn why it fails?

Can you please help?

Best regards

MY CODE

```
$query = "UPDATE tags SET count = ?  
WHERE tag IN(SELECT tag FROM (SELECT tag FROM tags LIMIT ?,1) as u)";

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
if($stmt === false) 
{
    trigger_error('SQL Error: ' . $mysqli->error, E_USER_ERROR);
}
$stmt->bind_param("ii", $count, $i);
$i = 0;
foreach ($array as $a) // $array: related values of the `count` column to be updated
{       
    $count = intval($a);
    $stmt->execute();       
    $i = $i + 1;
}
$stmt->close();
```

Comment: Can you get/create an array with the relevant `tag` values to go along with your `count` array in PHP?

Comment: I didn't however I think, yes I can if you mean array ("a"=>"2","b"=>"4" ... )

Comment: Yes, exactly. Then you could loop & build a query something like this: http://blog.bubble.ro/how-to-make-multiple-updates-using-a-single-query-in-mysql/

Comment: site is blocked for me in my work computer however I'll use it at home. Thank you so much friend and lastly, do you have any comment why my solution fails? (sql or any other suspecious point you consider?)

Comment: You know what, I didn't look very closely & didn't even see the `foreach`. I bet if you move your `bind_param()` inside the `foreach` it might work.