# Cant make a mysql query with update and limit work

Tags: mysql, sql-update, limit

I'm working on a script where I need to use this code:

```
UPDATE articles 
  SET name="Alianza oro rosa y diamante ", 
      desc="Alianza oro rosa y diamante " 
LIMIT 0, 1
```

What should I do to make it work?

Comment: What are you trying to do? More information would help.

Comment: see the comment in the answer bellow plz

Comment: You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)'s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works if yu omit the `0,`:

```
UPDATE articles 
  SET name        = "Alianza oro rosa y diamante ", 
      description = "Alianza oro rosa y diamante " 
LIMIT 1;
```

As per [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) you cannot add an offset in the `LIMIT` clause. Unfortunately LIMIT doesn't work in sub queries.

Check [this Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/227bb/2).

***p.s.***: potential solution (as per comment):

```
UPDATE articles 
  SET donttouch = false -- reset marker
WHERE donttouch = true; 

UPDATE articles 
  SET donttouch = true 
LIMIT 1; -- offset

UPDATE articles 
   SET name        = "Alianza oro rosa y diamante ", 
       description = "Alianza oro rosa y diamante " 
 WHERE donttouch = false
 LIMIT 1; -- number of entries
```

Tough this uses an addtional column ([Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9d88c/1)).

Comment: the problem is that i need to go through all the line of the table changing them one by one (with a while statement), so the idea is to go like this:          LIMIT 0, 1       LIMIT 1, 1        LIMIT 2, 1     and all the way through

Comment: damn it... so i guess the only way i can go is to delete all rows and rewrite them

Comment: @chino: I tried a few things (sub select, parametrzed views, ...) but none of my ideas were really nice. The closed was based on the idea of this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10728775/limit-offset-or-offset-in-an-update-sql-query; so my version derivd from this was http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/10b66/1

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge the limit clause only takes one number, not the x, y format like in a select statement.

```
UPDATE articles 
  SET name="Alianza oro rosa y diamante ", 
      desc="Alianza oro rosa y diamante " 
LIMIT 1
```