# mySQL LIMIT OFFSET not working with update

Tags: mysql

This works fine:

```
SELECT * FROM glinks_BuildRelations WHERE cat_id = 284 LIMIT 10,100
```

Yet when tring to do an update, I get:

```
UPDATE glinks_BuildRelations SET page_num = 1 WHERE cat_id = 284 LIMIT 10,100
```

The error is no help:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '100' at line 1

What gives?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LIMIT offset or OFFSET in an UPDATE SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10728775/limit-offset-or-offset-in-an-update-sql-query)

Comment: @CyrilleConMorales thanks - still the same error. I even tried `LIMIT 100 OFFSET 10`

Comment: possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6289729/mysql-update-query-with-limit)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`LIMIT` cannot be directly used this way with a MySQL update statement.  We can get around this error by using a subquery to find the matching records you want to update:

```
UPDATE glinks_BuildRelations
SET page_num = 1
WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM (
                 SELECT id FROM glinks_BuildRelations WHERE cat_id = 284
                 ORDER BY some_col LIMIT 10, 100)x );
```

I assume here that `id` is a primary key column in your table.  Note that using `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` is fairly meaningless, because you aren't telling MySQL *which* records you want to retain.

Comment: Thanks - I get an error with this though (after updating my field names): `very derived table must have its own alias`

Comment: You didn't copy my answer then, which _does_ give the derived table an alias of `x`.

Comment: @TimBiegelisen haha I thought that was a typo so removed it :) That seems to work - thanks