# MySQL update one of many similar rows

Tags: python, mysql

I need some tips on how to update random MySQL rows with specific serial one by one. I program mysql on Python.

Check the MySQL table here:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4f8fff/1

For example, if I have 2 rows with the same `Serial` column, I want to only modify one of them not both.

```
sql = "UPDATE device_Data SET Status='DONE' WHERE Serial = %s"
cur.execute(sql,('ab111222',)
```

The SQL query above will modify both rows, but I only want to modify one at a time because the queries run in a loop and do extra checking.

Is there a method to update a single random row with my where serial condition

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LIMIT offset or OFFSET in an UPDATE SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10728775/limit-offset-or-offset-in-an-update-sql-query)

Comment: I have tried to execute this sql querry on sql fiddle but with no luck. Check : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4f8fff/12 .  I am not able to see whats the problem. Still looking for a possible solution to this

Comment: I have also saw this example: https://www.plus2net.com/sql_tutorial/sql_rand-update.php.  ```UPDATE device_Data SET status1='DONE' ORDER BY RAND() limit 1;```. However, that does not seem to work either

Comment: Have you tried that? `UPDATE device_Data SET status1 = 'DONE' WHERE tutorial_id IN(SELECT tutorial_id FROM device_Data WHERE status1 = 'IDLE' LIMIT 1)`

Comment: It is possible that it does not allow me to execute this kind of querry due to sqlfiddle limitations. I will have to try that tommorow on my actual server. It may work there.